# How to fix a bad checksum error on mdadm raid5 array (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm, software-raid, raid5

I have a `4 x 4 TB` drive configured in a raid5 array.

Drives labeled as `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdc1`, `/dev/sdd1` & `/dev/sde1` assembled as `/dev/md0`

**mdadm assemble output**

When I tried to assemble the array I get:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md0: Invalid argument
```

**dmesg -T output**

The output of interest:

```
[Sun Dec 27 00:15:35 2020] md/raid:md0: device sdc1 operational as raid disk 0
[Sun Dec 27 00:15:35 2020] md/raid:md0: device sdd1 operational as raid disk 3
[Sun Dec 27 00:15:35 2020] md/raid:md0: device sdb1 operational as raid disk 2
[Sun Dec 27 00:15:35 2020] md/raid:md0: device sde1 operational as raid disk 1
[Sun Dec 27 00:15:35 2020] md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[Sun Dec 27 00:15:35 2020] md0: invalid bitmap file superblock: bad magic
[Sun Dec 27 00:15:35 2020] md0: failed to create bitmap (-22)
[Sun Dec 27 00:15:35 2020] md: md0 stopped.
```

**mdadm examine output**

All the drives seem normal to me with the exception of `/dev/sdc1`:

```
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 1546e1f3:18b8a99f:a6b9e7b9:f5ca4949
           Name : server:0  (local to host server)
  Creation Time : Mon Nov 19 17:36:22 2018
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7813769216 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 11720653824 (11177.69 GiB 12001.95 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 3cb78503:731a0dcb:8afc96d0:9a801d67
Update Time : Thu Dec 10 17:35:57 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : 4c2657ea - expected 4c2657e9
         Events : 10242
Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

The checksum shows **4c2657ea - expected 4c2657e9**

**My thoughts**

The checksum discrepancy is so similar that it makes me believe that a bit was flipped on my primary drive since any change in the 4TB drive would have changed the checksum dramatically. Thus, I think that the drive is OK and I've checked it with Ubuntu Disk utility (both SMART data and self-test) and using bad blocks. I've also checked it in windows using the Western Digital diagnostic tool. They all give it a pass.

My question is how do I go about restoring the array? Is it possible to `mdadm` to correct this? Or do I have to remove and add another drive to the array?

Thanks for your help in advance!